# Wordpress ACF plugin : Google Maps not working

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

I've added a Google Maps field, configured in the function.php my API key.

In edition, the map is showing, but I have errors in the console :

```
TypeError: _.N is not a function[En savoir plus]  stats.js:3:463
TypeError: _.ma is not a function[En savoir plus]  common.js:99:286
TypeError: _.ma is not a function[En savoir plus]  util.js:27:391
TypeError: invalid 'instanceof' operand _.je common.js:53:24
TypeError: e.getPath is not a function[En savoir plus]  util.js:209:272
TypeError: b is undefined[En savoir plus]  common.js:31:472
TypeError: a.b is not a function[En savoir plus] common.js:44:30
InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character common.js:19
TypeError: a.b is not a function[En savoir plus] common.js:44:30
TypeError: d is undefined[En savoir plus]
```

Has a result, I can't set a marker, nor search for a location, nor drag the map, and the location field become "null"

How can I solve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just add the same issue and solved it this way :

just don't add this lines to the functions.php file because it isn't necessary. Just add it to the single.php or the template where you want to display the map so it doesn't break.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'google-map', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY', array(), '3', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'google', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/acf-map.js', array('google-map', 'jquery'), '0.1', true );
```

It's certainely not a very clean solution since the good solution is to load it with the functions.php normally but it seems there are some conflicts with the $ sign...

Comment: Thanks for the help. You said to add this in single.php, but this will have no effect on the post.php when editing an article ?